# How is the planetary moons coordinate system oriented in PyEphem?

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

Meeus defines the coordinates such that x-axis coincides with the equator of the planet and y-axis with the planet's rotational axis. For the instant 1992 December 16 at 0h UT, Meeus finds the coordinates of the four Jovian mooon to be:

```
        X       Y
I     -3.45    0.21
II     7.44    0.28
III    1.20    0.59
IV     7.07    1.03
```

For the same instant, PyEphem gives:

```
        X       Y
I      3.26    1.26
II    -6.65   -3.33
III   -0.84   -1.09
IV    -5.98   -3.95
```

(Note that signs are opposite due to Meeus using the convention: + west, + north and PyEphem + east, + south.)

However, the coordinates do match up when rotated by about 25 degrees. All Quick References mention is that planetary moons coordinates are given relative to the planet in planetary radii.

Answer (score 0):

When the Quick Reference uses points of the compass like “east” and “north” with respect to those coordinates —

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html

```
Position of moon relative to planet (measured in planet radii)
* x — offset +east or –west
* y — offset +south or –north
* z — offset +front or –behind
```

— it is referring very specifically to those exact cardinal directions, which are the axes (on Earth) of longitude and latitude, and (in the sky) of right ascension and declination.

So they are offsets designed to be added and subtract from the planet’s own RA and dec coordinates, in case someone wants to know where the satellite itself is in the sky.

The roughly-25-degree tilt you correctly identified is in fact the 23.5 degree tilt of the Earth's equator, and thus of the RA/dec coordinate system, relative to the ecliptic and the plane of Jupiter's rotation (which is only barely tilted from it, by about 3 degrees).